# libvlc, taking snapshot gives: core stream error: cannot pre fill buffer

Tags: c++, mutex, libvlc

I have implemented the [libvlc SDL2 example](https://wiki.videolan.org/LibVLC_SampleCode_SDL/) and it works just fine. I changed it such that it plays back a video and not a stream. Now all I want to do is take a snapshot of the video. The code looks like this:

```
libvlc_video_set_format(mp, "RV16", VIDEOWIDTH, VIDEOHEIGHT, VIDEOWIDTH * 2);
libvlc_media_player_play(mp);
libvlc_video_set_callbacks(mp, lock, unlock, display, &context);
libvlc_video_take_snapshot(mp, 0, "C:\\temp\\test3.png", width, height);
```

and this does not produce the snapshot but executes and exits healthy. On the console I get

```
core stream error: cannot pre fill buffer
```

which confuses me quite a bit. The buffler should be filled since the mutex in function unlock was unlocked, or am I getting something wrong?

If I add sleep() for 1s between the media playback and the snapshot call, it works. It just seems like it needs more time to fill the buffer somehow. But in this one second the video has moved on and I wanted my snapshot at the time right after it started playing.

Hope somebody can help me out here.

Best regards,
Pat